# Why Arc GIS Raster calculator is not working?

Tags: python, gis

i want to do satellite image base calculations by using Arc GIS Raster calculator. But when i run some calculations, it gives above error which i attached as a image.

[image]

Always this is happening when i am using raster calculator.then i checked Arc GIS solution portal. then they gave following solutions which i attached as 2nd image:

[image]

how i can fix it.

Comment: I do believe that this is not an appropriate segment to get the solution, you need to add Python Tag with question !!

Comment: A better place to ask this might be [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Was numpy installed along with ArcGIS itself, or did you install it separately?

Comment: @grawity separately

Comment: And which version did you install?

Comment: @grawity NumPy v1.16